# Trying to create a SOAP packet that looks like this:

Tags: c#, soap

I am investigating an existing system that relies on SOAP messages to be passed between the various executables.  I am trying to replace one of those applications with one of my own, and looking at the documentation, I am running into a difficulty.

I haven't worked with SOAP prior to this and am not sure what tools to use to accomplish this task, nor even what keywords I should be searching for.  What I need to do is to be able to create a SOAP message that looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
> <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <GetSpecialList xmlns="SpecialManagerAPI"/> </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And, I need to send it via TCP to the local IP (127.0.0.1) port 1234 and get responses from it.  How do I create above message and what is an easy way to send it?

Comment: Does the publishing end have a wsdl available? If so, you can bring the service into you own executable using the service reference feature.

Comment: For instance, a publishing WebService will give you something like:  http://localhost:1234/TheService?wsdl . Using this, you can import the webservice into your VS project by adding a Service Reference to your project using the WSDL url from the publisher

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you take some time to learn at least a little about web services. You are already off on the wrong track in terms of thinking about creating and sending messages.

One good resource is [Getting Started with Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-getting-started.aspx). Also, see the webcast [Overview (Level 100)](http://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032344313&CountryCode=US).

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.HttpRequestClass would be the bare bones way of doing this.  You'll need to set the headers appropriately (especially the "SOAPAction" header).  However I'd advise you against doing this!  Find the [wsdl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) for the service and use it to build your classes with either [AddWebReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) in Visual Studio or [Wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx).  This will build a well formed class  for you (or several) to work with!

Answer (score 0):

You have three basic options:

1. If the service has a WSDL or DISCO service description you can connect to it via Add Service Reference (VS 2008 and VS 2005 with certain WCF addons) or Add Web Reference (VS 2005). The command line equivalents of those tools to generate soap client classes are svcutil.exe and wsdl.exe respectively.
2. You can do as [C. Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16487/c-ross) suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014049/trying-to-create-a-soap-packet-that-looks-like-this/1014111#1014111)and use the [HttpRequestClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) using a custom built string.
3. You can is the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class to create the xml message and use the HttpRequest class to send it. I suggest you make a template xml document and save it as an embedded resource in your executable. You can then do xpath queries to modify the parameters.